# Why I can't see my root variable component in the console when I'm into subscribe method of Subject call by another component (angular 2/4/5)?

Tags: angular, typescript, console

When put a debugger breakpoint in a method of the component with angular 5, I can see the content of my root variable "this.nodes" when I over it with the cursor of my mouse.

[image]

But when I type my variable in the console, it is undefined !?

[image]

@edit: I was able to identify when variables is not reachable, this happen when I am in subscribe method of Subject. Call by another component.

And is there a way to type my variable in the console ?

Comment: This seems like a valid question ... not sure why it got voted down. (I would like to see the vote down functionality removed.) Anyway, it is hard to see what's going on in the code with the popup on top of it, but it appears that you are pausing before reaching the variable you want to see? (I just tried something similar in my code and the general technique works fine ... try it with another variable just to be sure)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with my other variables and they are all undefined.

Comment: And after or before the pausing changes nothing...

Comment: What browser are you using? And what *exact* steps are you using to display your variables?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and what I can tell you is that the only way I found to be able to inspect my variables is to type the variable in the method to inspect it with my mouse with breakpoint. And in my older other projects too, if I remember well.

Comment: Have you tried a watch instead: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#watch

Comment: I was able to identify when this effect is happening, this happen when I am in subscribe method of Subject. Call by another component.

Answer (score 1):

console's environment is window object. 'this.nodes' environment is a component of angular